# Javascript: Can't get variable sum to work with addition operator

Tags: javascript

I can't get the var total to resolve by using addition. It will work with multiplication operator:
var total = subtotal * sales_tax
but not with the + sign addition operator: var total = subtotal + sales_tax. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
var calculate_click = function () { 
    var subtotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("subtotal").value).toFixed(3); 
    var taxRate  = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax_rate").value).toFixed(3);  

    if (isNaN(subtotal) || isNaN(taxRate)) {    
    } 
        else {                                  
        var sales_tax = (subtotal * taxRate / 100); 
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("sales_tax").value = sales_tax.toFixed(3));  

        var total = subtotal + sales_tax;   
        parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(3));  
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what's the output? Can you link to a running example (JSFiddle or StackOverflow's new code editor)?

Comment: Also the calls to `parseFloat()` around the code where you set the field values are pointless.

Comment: Why you put input values assign into `parseFloat`?

Comment: Your indentation is a little misleading. It makes it look like the else is *inside* the if block.

Comment: @EricNguyen 
Well, it works in my browser, but apparently not in JSFiddle. The result is simply a blank space when trying to get a total.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ronando/m9jLt0L2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** formats the number into a *string*. So arithmetic operations afterwards will not work as expected.

**Note:**

- `+` (concatenation) is a valid operation for strings as well, so it'll return `"string1string2"` - For all other arithmetic operations it auto converts the strings to numbers and performs the operation. If the data within the strings cannot be converted, it returns `NaN`.
- `"12" + "2" => "122"` whereas `"12" * "2" => 24 (number)` and `"hello" * "3" => NaN`

Comment: but the string will work with a multiplication operator? That's what confused me, the the formula worked with multiplication but not addition.

Comment: Thats because `+` (concatenation) is a valid operation for strings as well, so it'll return "string1string2" - For all other arithmetic operations it will *auto* convert the strings to numbers and perform the operation (when possible, otherwise it returns `NaN`).

Comment: `"12" + "2"` gives `"122"` whereas `"12" * "2"` gives `24` and `"hello" * "3"` gives `NaN`

Comment: I see! That makes sense. Thanks. Previously I thought it might have to do with being a string, so I tried parsing it, but I still couldn't get it to work. Can you help in getting it to work? 

Also, I seem to have trouble in understanding parsing since others say I don't need it on the subtotal and taxRate variables. When I remove the parse, it doesn't work due to the parentheses (which I can't find where to put). 
var subtotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("subtotal").value).toFixed(3);

Comment: Yes! That was perfect! I should have known it was something that simple. Thank you. This is very helpful and allowed me to complete my homework after 6 hours of slamming my head against the keyboard.